# BinarySearch in a SortedArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a faster way than what I currently have to add an element to a sorted array list. Currently this is my strategy

```
public void insertSorted(E value) {
    add(value);
    for (int i = size() - 1; i > 0 && value.compareTo(get(i - 1)) < 0; i--) {
        this.swap(i);
    }
}
```

and my add method...

```
public void add(E element) {
    ensureCapacity();
    array[size++] = element;
}
```

So I read that using a binary search algorithm I could more efficiently find the best way to put an element even faster.

I tried developing that, but somehow it always outputs me 0.

```
private int binarySearch(E value) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = this.size()-1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        E midVal = this.get(mid);
        int cmp = midVal.compareTo(value);

        if (cmp < 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return low;
}


public void insertSorted(E value) {
    int searchResult = binarySearch(value);
    add(value, searchResult);
    System.out.println("Value: " + value + ". Position = " + searchResult);

}
```

Could someone help me out? If necessary I will show full code

Comment: Did you override the ``hashcode`` and ``equals`` methods for the types in your ``SortedArrayList`` ?

Comment: I didnt... how could that help me?

Comment: You are using ``midVal.compareTo(value)`` in your method. You have to give it a rule of comparing.

Comment: I implement comparable in the object i pass in as argument in insertSorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than developing your own binary search, use built-in [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) implementation. However, this wouldn't give you much improvement over your original version in terms of time.

To see why, consider the steps that you take to place the value in the sorted sequence:

- Find the insertion position
- Move items to the right of insertion position by one
- Place the element into insertion position

The first step can be done in O(log<sub>2</sub>N). The second step takes O(N). The last step takes O(1). Overall, insertion's time complexity is O(log<sub>2</sub>N + N + 1), which is the same as O(N). The algorithm is dominated by the second step, so you might as well use linear search as you move items to the right by one.

Comment: Great explanation. So I wouldnt really have improvements in time. Thanks for the answer

Comment: If you want a faster way, i.e, O(log N) operations for both insertion and searching, consider using Binary Search Trees (BSTs). TreeMap in Java implements a BST.

Comment: I would like to add one more thing: the sorted array approach is good, if you have many searches but few insertions. If you have many insertions and few search operations, just use an unsorted array and iterate over them. If you want O(log N) guarantee for both searching and inserting use a BST.

Comment: Thanks @Wickoo, very appreciated :) Will look into that